# How to keep a function going after different function has been called?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I believe my program is freezing after:

```
if pressed(win.getMouse(), startImage):
   task = 'start'
   timeFormat()
```

Basically, what I'm trying to do is when the mouse point is on stopImage the timer will stop, and when the mouse click is on lapTimer, it will reset. When I take out

```
timeFormat()
```

the program will run through the while and then break. My stop and start button work, but not my lap button. How can i make it NOT stop the program after the stop button is pressed? So that I can hit start again or reset?

```
def pressed(pt, image):

    width = image.getWidth()
    height = image.getHeight()
    anchor = image.getAnchor()

    x1 = (anchor.getX()) - (.5 * width)
    x2 = (anchor.getX()) + (.5 * width)
    y1 = (anchor.getY()) - (.5 * height)
    y2 = (anchor.getY()) + (.5 * height)

    return(x1 <= pt.getX() <= x2 and y1 <= pt.getY() <= y2)



def timeFormat():

    sec = 0
    minute = 0
    hour = 0
    timeDisplay = "{0:02d}:{1:02d}:{2:02d}".format(hour, minute, sec)
    timer.setText(timeDisplay)


    while task == 'start':
        task = 'start'
        time.sleep(1)
        sec += 1
        if sec == 60:
            sec = 0
            minute += 1
        if minute == 60:
            sec = 0
            minute = 0
            hour += 1

        timeDisplay = "{0:02d}:{1:02d}:{2:02d}".format(hour, minute, sec)
        timer.setText(timeDisplay)
        check = win.checkMouse()
       if check != None:
            if pressed(check, stopImage):
                task = 'stop'
                print('asd')
                if pressed(check, startImage):
                    task = 'start'


        if pressed(check, lapImage):
            sec = 0
            minute = 0
            hour = 0
            task = 'stop


def main():

    while not pressed(win.getMouse(), startImage):
        if task == 'stop':
            break
        if task == 'reset':
            sec = 0
            minute = 0
            hour = 0
            break
        continue
    timeFormat()

main()
```

Comment: Have you asyncio? Examples found on [18.5.3. Tasks and coroutines — Python 3.5.2 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html)

Comment: Hello, I do not have time to learn this new function unfortunately. There is a way to make mine work, I'm just doing something out of order.

Answer (score 0):

Your `timeFormat` function never returns, so the calling code can't continue.

Your main loop has the condition `while sec < 60`, but every time `sec` is incremented to `60`, it gets reset to zero again. This means the loop will never end.

It's not clear to me when you expect it to end, so I can't necessarily tell you how to fix the issue, but generally it's a bad idea when writing an interactive program to have multiple event loops unless you have a well defined structure for switching between them.

You have a lot of loops, and when one of them is running, all the others will necessarily be stuck waiting. Try moving some of the logic from separate loops into other functions that can be called from a single main loop.

Comment: Hello @Blckknght , thank you for your reply! I'm new to programming so bare with me. The program is a stop watch, and it never closes until the user just closes it him/herself. What I am trying to do is just make it start when start is clicks, stop when stop is clicked, and same for reset (which is called lapImage) I am having trouble when and where to call the functions and use the loops. I believe I have it all jumbled.

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do was switch some if statements around.